# Elasticsearch - How to get the latest record in each group with filter?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, greatest-n-per-group

I have a few records in elastic search I want to group the record by `user_id` and fetch the latest record which is `event_type` is `1`

If the latest record `event_type` value is not `1` then we should not fetch that record. I did it in MySQL query. Please let me know how can I do that same in elastic search.

[image]

After executing the MySQL query

```
SELECT * FROM user_events
     WHERE id IN( SELECT max(id) FROM `user_events` group by user_id ) AND event_type=1;
```

[image]

I need the same output in elasticsearch aggregations.

**Elasticsearch Query:**

```json
GET test_analytic_report/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "event_date": {
              "gte": "2022-10-01",
              "lte": "2023-02-06"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "event_date": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "_source": ["user_id", "event_date", "event_type"],
            "sort": {
              "user_id": "desc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have the above query I have two users whose user_id is 55 and 56. So, in my aggregations, it should not come. But It fetched the other event_type data but I want only event_types=1 with the latest one. if the user's last record does not have event_type=1, it should not come.

In the above table, user_id 56 latest record event_type contains 2 so it should not come in our aggregations.

I tried but it's not returning the exact result that I want.

*Note: `event_date` is the current date and time. As per the above image, I have inserted it manually that's why the date differs*

Answer (score 0):

```
GET user_events/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "event_type": 1
      }
    },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Explanation: This is an Elasticsearch API request in JSON format. It retrieves the latest event of type 1 (specified by "event_type": 1 in the query) from the "user_events" index, with a size of 1 (specified by "size": 1) and sorts the results in descending order by the "id" field (specified by "order": "desc" in the sort).

Answer (score 0):

If your ES version supports, you can do it with field collapse feature. Here is an example query:

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "event_type": 1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "user_id",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "the_record",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "id": "desc"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "id": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the response, you will see that the document you want is in `inner_hits` under the name you give. In my example it is `the_record`. You can change the size of the inner hits if you want more records in each group and sort them.

Comment: I want these in aggression with count how many users found which event_type=1 in last record.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

They are many ways to go about it:

- Sorting
- Collapsing
- [Latest Transform](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-overview.html#latest-transform-overview)

All those solution are approximate of what you could get with sql.

But my personal favourite is `transform`

## Solution - transform jobs

#### Set up

We create 2 users, with 2 events.

```json
PUT 75324839/_bulk
{"create":{}}
{"user_id": 1, "type": 2, "date": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"create":{}}
{"user_id": 1, "type": 1, "date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"create":{}}
{"user_id": 2, "type": 1, "date": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"create":{}}
{"user_id": 2, "type": 2, "date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

### Transform job

This transform job is going to run against the index `75324839`.
It will find the latest document, with regard to the `user_id`, based of the value in `date` field.

And the results are going to be stored in `latest_75324839`.

```json
PUT _transform/75324839
{
  "source": {
    "index": [
      "75324839"
    ]
  },
  "latest": {
    "unique_key": [
      "user_id"
    ],
    "sort": "date"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "latest_75324839"
  }
}
```

If you were to query `latest_75324839`
You would find:

```json
{
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "latest_75324839",
        "_id": "AGvuZWuqqz7c5ytICzX5Z74AAAAAAAAA",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "user_id": 1,
          "type": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "latest_75324839",
        "_id": "AA3tqz9zEwuio1D73_EArycAAAAAAAAA",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
          "user_id": 2,
          "type": 2
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Get the final results

To get the amount of user with `type=1`.
A simple search query such as:

```json
GET latest_75324839/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "type": {
        "value": 1
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "number_of_user": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "user_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Side notes

This transform job has been running in batch, this means it will only run once.

It is possible to run it in a [continuous fashion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-scale.html), to get all the time the latest event for a `user_id`.

[Here are some examples](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for an [SQL HAVING clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp), which would allow you to filter results after grouping. But sadly there is nothing equivalent on Elastic.

So it is not possible to

- [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sort-search-results.html), [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) and filter afterwards (even [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/filter-search-results.html#post-filter) does not
  help here)
- use a [top_hits aggregation with custom sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) and then filter
- use any [map/reduce scripted aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html), as they do not support
  sorting.
- work with subqueries.

So basically seen, Elastic is not a database. Any sorting or relation to other documents should be based on scoring. And the score should be calculated independently for each document, distributed on shards.

But there is a tiny loophole, which might be the solution for your use case. It is based on a [top_metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-metrics.html) aggregation followed by [bucket selector](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html) to eliminate the unwanted event types:

**GET test_analytic_report/_search**

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "tm": {
          "top_metrics": {
            "metrics": {
              "field": "event_type"
            },
            "sort": [
              {
                "id": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "event_type_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "event_type": "tm.event_type"
            },
            "script": "params.event_type == 1"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you require more fields from the source document you can add them to the top_metrics.
It is sorted by id now, but you can also use event_date.

Comment: I got error message. Please check screenshot - https://ibb.co/QckvQkD

Comment: @Chinmay235 Which ES version do you have?

Comment: I am using v 7.2.1

Comment: Oh, that's pretty old - From Summer 2019. The top_metrics aggregation was introduced in 7.7.0:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/release-notes-7.7.0.html
I highly recommend an update.

Comment: What is the maximum length of `"size": 100`?

Comment: The default is 10, but you can increase it to much higher values: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-metrics.html#_size_2

Comment: I have 10 lacs record. Is it possible to fetch all data in one request?

Comment: How many distinct user_ids do you have? Then set `size` (on the aggregation) and `top_metrics_max_size` (in the settings) accordingly as described in the link above.